# How do I group SQL Server rows in Table A by date in Table B

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is simple in theory, but difficult for me to figure out.

I have two SQL Server tables:

1. List of purchases with purchase date and total

   ```
   select total, date from purchases
   ```
2. list of miles traveled for a specific job and date of travel

   ```
   select travelDate, miles from trips
   ```

**EDIT:** To keep the answer/discussion on my question, I am rephrasing the requirement.

I need to figure out the total miles driven between each purchase.

I want more accuracy than an overall average.

I can manually get this by summing all miles from `trips` in between each `purchases` date. Now, I just want to automate the process.

The grouping should be such that all `trips` dates greater than `purchases` date A and less than `purchases` date B are part of the `purchases` date A group.

Comment: Various joins and sums and nothing even gets me close.  I think I can figure it out with a start, but none of the results have been usable.  I am not trying to be vague, I just didn't get anything useful.  In Excel I would do a Vlookup because it would find the closest next smallest value.

Comment: Are you basing your model on the assumption that the fuel tank is completely emptied each time? The problem with a naive calculation here of `[miles per trip] / [miles for all trips since the last purchase] * [total from last purchase]` is that while the moving vehicle "spends" the *price per unit* of the last purchase, the *amount* of the last purchase has the volume filled embedded in it. In order to calculate properly, we need the "gallons/liters filled" of purchases as well, including the *next* purchase after a trip! (Continued)

Comment: If one purchase was only for half a tank, but all the trips before the next purchase completely emptied the tank, you will get a very low cost per trip not reflecting the real cost at all. It's even more complicated with the half-full-tank because in fact half the fuel is the new price and half is the old price... and there could even be fuel that's in the tank from the time before that and the time before that. All of this can actually be accounted for, but we need the volume per fill in order to do anything with the data.

Comment: assuming a full tank at each fill-up (which they do), then if I spend $50 on gas to travel 100 miles, then those 100 miles cost $0.50/mi regardless of how much fuel I actually used.

Comment: aside from all that, I am looking for a way to group `trip` records by the `purchases` record with the next closest smallest date.  Let's frame it another way and say I want to get a count of `trip` records that happened between each `purchases` record.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15100/discussion-between-davids-and-erike)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curing my denseness, I see that your request is quite reasonable by treating the problem as "replacement fuel cost"—thus using the fuel cost of the *next fueling* rather than the previous cost to buy the fuel actually used (which gets really complicated, really fast). Volume then doesn't matter. Try this on for size.

```
SELECT
   T.*,
   P.*, -- from previous purchase
   N.*, -- from next purchase (NULL if none yet)
   TripCost = N.Total * T.Miles / M.MilesThisFill
FROM
   dbo.Trips T
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM dbo.Purchases P
      WHERE P.[Date] < T.travelDate
      ORDER BY P.[Date] DESC
   ) P
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM dbo.Purchases P
      WHERE P.[Date] > T.travelDate
      ORDER BY P.[Date]
   ) N
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT Sum(miles) MilesThisFill
      FROM dbo.Trips T2
      WHERE
         T2.[Date] > P.[Date]
         AND T2.[Date] < N.[Date]
   ) M;
```

Or here's a version that thinks very differently about the problem but should give the same result. Let me know which one performs better, would ya? (`SET STATISTICS IO ON; SET STATISTICS TIME ON;`)

```
WITH PSeq AS (
   SELECT
      Seq = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]),
      *
   FROM dbo.Purchases
), Slices AS (
   SELECT
      FromDate = P.[Date],
      ToDate = N.[Date],
      N.Total
   FROM
      PSeq P
      INNER JOIN PSeq N
         ON P.Seq + 1 = N.Seq
), TotalMiles AS (
    SELECT
       S.FromDate,
       Sum(T.Miles) MilesThisFill
    FROM
      Slices S
      INNER JOIN dbo.Trips T
         ON T.travelDate BETWEEN S.FromDate AND S.ToDate
    GROUP BY
       S.FromDate 
)
SELECT
   T.travelDate,
   S.FromDate,
   S.ToDate,
   TripCost = S.Total * T.Miles / M.MilesThisFill
FROM
   Slices S
   INNER JOIN dbo.Trips T
      ON T.travelDate BETWEEN S.FromDate AND S.ToDate 
   INNER JOIN dbo.TotalMiles M
      ON S.FromDate = L.FromDate;
```

I apologize in advance for any typos or errors... I haven't tested the code.

And just for laughs, here's the first query transmogrified into a version that would work even on SQL Server 2000!

```
SELECT
   T.travelDate,
   T.Miles,
   T.ToDate,
   TripCost = P.Total * T.Miles / M.MilesThisFill
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         T.travelDate,
         T.Miles,
         ToDate = (
            SELECT TOP 1 P.Date
            FROM dbo.Purchases P
            WHERE P.[Date] > T.travelDate
            ORDER BY P.[Date]
         )
      FROM
         dbo.Trips T
   ) T
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
         ToDate = (
            SELECT TOP 1 P.Date
            FROM dbo.Purchases P
            WHERE P.[Date] > T2.travelDate
            ORDER BY P.[Date]
         ),
         MilesThisFill = Sum(T2.Miles)
      FROM dbo.Trips T2
      GROUP BY
         (
            SELECT TOP 1 P.Date
            FROM dbo.Purchases P
            WHERE P.[Date] > T2.travelDate
            ORDER BY P.[Date]
         )
   ) M ON T.ToDate = M.ToDate
   INNER JOIN dbo.Purchases P
      ON T.ToDate = P.[Date];
```

This actually exposes that I might not need to look up the previous purchase date in my first query, if I do it right... so here's a final version:

```
WITH TripData AS (
   SELECT
      T.Miles,
      T.travelDate,
      ToDate = (
         SELECT TOP 1 P.[Date]
         FROM dbo.Purchases P
         WHERE P.[Date] > T.travelDate
         ORDER BY P.[Date]
      )
   FROM
      dbo.Trips T
)
SELECT
   T.*,
   P.*,
   TripCost = P.Total * T.Miles / M.MilesThisFill
FROM
   TripData T
   INNER JOIN dbo.Purchases P
      ON T.ToDate = P.[Date]
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
         T2.ToDate,
         Sum(T2.Miles) MilesThisFill
      FROM TripData T2
      GROUP BY
         T2.ToDate
   ) M ON T.ToDate = M.ToDate;
```

Note: the order of the TripCost expression is important, because Miles and TotalMiles are integers. If you put P.Total last, you will get wrong answers because Miles / TotalMiles will be converted to an integer.

Comment: This is looking very promising.  I don't understand why you are selecting all from `P` twice.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @davids It was just a typo, please see my update. You may not even want all that data--just an example.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to point me in the right direction.  Thanks!!!  For feedback, the slices method appears to produce the most accurate results (after I broke it down to understand).  The last method is simplest, but the results aren't quite right.  That may be mostly because my live db is far more complex than the simple example I provided.

Comment: @davids they should have given the same results. But I did do something different: I used `<` and `>` for some queries and `<=` and `>=` for other queries (a.k.a. `BETWEEN`). If you adjust the other queries to use inclusive end points, do you get better results? Also, I had an *awful* typo in my second query. `ON P.Seq + 1 = N.Seq + 1` should have been `ON P.Seq + 1 = N.Seq` (now updated). Please advise...

Comment: @davids One more thing: Using inclusive start and end dates is likely wrong. If any trips match the exact date of a purchase, then that trip will count for both prior and next purchase, which is incorrect.

Comment: I had noticed those and corrected them already.  I was able to get it the rest of the way to what I needed, I just had no idea how to even approach it.

Comment: @davids So has this worked out for you? I'd be interested to see you post your final query at the end of your question.

Comment: It did work for me thanks!  Unfortunately, my final query is complex and long and won't work here.  I stripped it down to the base elements for my question.  I just needed to know how to approach it and your help pointed me in the right direction.  I ended up using something like your "different approach" (second example). Thank you again, I really appreciate it.